# Can the number of tasks submitted to a thread pool be limited

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario that I have a thread pool with 100 threads for example.

There are 10 jobs, each of these jobs can send 1..n tasks to the thread pool.

If I just submit them directly, they will job compete for the threads in the pool.

Is there any way I can say something like:

**Job 1 can submit a maximum of 5 tasks to the thread pool at the same time and have to wait for one of them to complete before sending the next one.**

I know I can do this if I have separate thread pools for each job. But these jobs are incoming requests that appear and dissapear on the fly. It might not be good to dynamically create thread pools this way.

Can I achieve the above using one single big thread pool?

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks. Edited the question.

Comment: @ZZZ and the title?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `ExecutorService`, something like:

```
class LimitingExecutorService implements ExecutorService {
  private final ExecutorService delegate;
  private final Semaphore semaphore;

  LimitingExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate, int limit) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.semaphore = new Semaphore(limit);
  }
```

Now, you can implement the methods to delegate the call to `delegate`, but checking that the semaphore can be acquired, e.g.:

```
  public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    // Or you could block.
    if (!semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
      throw new RejectedExecutionException(...); // Indicate that the task couldn't be submitted.
    }

    // Wrap task with in another runnable() that releases the semaphore (whether or not it succeeds).
    try {
      return delegate.submit(() -> {
        try {
          task.run();
        } finally {
          semaphore.release();
        }
      });
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
      semaphore.release();
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

etc for other methods.

You will need to take care around methods like `invokeAll` to decide what the behavior should be: should they invoke as many as they can, or should that call only succeed if all tasks can be scheduled at that moment.

Now, each of your jobs can have their own instance of `LimitingExecutorService`, and they can only submit as many jobs as the semaphore's available permits allow.